# Didn't get values properly from table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the id of a user who who refered another user from user_id, see this sample data:

```
     | user_id | refered |
     |---------+---------|
     |     780 |       1 |
     |     781 |     780 |
     |     782 |     781 |
     |     783 |         |
     |     784 |         |
```

This is my query which I am using but I want to get user_id from the database, not from the session, how can I do this?

```
SELECT * FROM  user where refered = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'
```

I also tried this, which didn't work either:

```
 SELECT * FROM  user where refered = user_id
```

I want to get the id of a user who who refered another user from user_id

Comment: Add sample result that you want to get to your question.

Comment: with my second query i get blank means nothing get values

Comment: Add not what you get, but what you want to get.

Comment: I want to get user_id who refer from user_id the database, not from the session

Comment: your first query should work. Is your actual question about how to replace `$_SESSION['userid']` with a variable (id) that was fetched from a DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all users who have referred someone, `JOIN` table to itself as below

```
SELECT b.user_id, b.refered
FROM user a JOIN user b ON a.user_id = b.refered;
```

Above query will return same user twice if a user has referred more than one user.

Comment: where i add another column in this query, means refered i want to see

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: and when i want to see it's income can i add there c.income :)

Comment: absolutely! You can add as many columns desired. To view all rows, add `SELECT a.*, b.*` or simply `SELECT *`

Comment: but i get this error :- #1054 - Unknown column 'c.refincome' in 'field list'

Comment: where do you get income from? is it in the same table? If yes, you need to use `b.income` because `a` is an alias of table. In my query `c` is not created anywhere.

Comment: so how i get another column is this any solution.

Comment: For that you need to post your exact requirement and complete table structure so that I can help.

Comment: samir your answer is right and thanks for help i just want to get another columns with this query

Comment: If you want to get other columns from `user` table, you can add them like this `SELECT b.user_id, b.refered, b.income, b.age` and so on. Hope this helps!